# KeyError: <class '__main__.Node'> (python)

Tags: python

first im really sorry for not so good at english

in the method search doesnt work. i know x.key and key both has a same value but it cant pass the if function.
So i try the type of x.key and key.  Key has a int type, x.key has <class '**main**.Node'>
help plase with soulution and explanation.

i want function s.remove(s.search(44)) to work
i approciate your help

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key = None):
        self.key = key
        self.prev = self
        self.next = self
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.key)   
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
        self.size =0
    def __iter__(self):
        v= self.head.next      
        while(v!=self.head):
            yield v
            v= v.next
    def __str__(self):
        return "->".join(str(v) for v in self)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.size
    def splice(self,a,b,x):  #노드 a부터b까지 떼어내 노드 x뒤에 붙여넣는 연산
        if(a== None or b==None or x==None): return
        ap= a.prev
        bn = b.next

        ap.next = bn
        bn.prev = ap

        xn = x.next
        xn.prev = b
        b.next = xn
        a.prev = x
        x.next = a
    def search(self,key):   #return the Node which has the key value or None
        for x in self:
            print(type(key))            #just for checking
            print(type(x.key))     #just for checking
            if x.key == key:
                return x       
        return None
    def isEmpty(self): #빈 리스트면 트루 아니면 펄스
        return self.size ==0
    def first(self):    #처음 노드를 리턴 빈 리스트면  None 리턴
        if self.size ==0:
            return None
        else:
            return self.head.next
    def last(self): 
        if self.size ==0:
            return None
        else:
            return self.head.prev
    
    def moveAfter(self,a,x): #노드a를 노드x뒤로 이동
        self.splice(a,a,x)
    def moveBefor(self,a,x):
        self.splice(a,a,x.prev)
    def insertAfter(self,x,key):    #노드 x뒤에 데이터가 key인 새 노드를 생성해서 삽입
        self.moveAfter(Node(key),x)
        self.size += 1
    def insertBefor(self,x,key):
        self.moveBefor(Node(key),x)
        self.size += 1
    def pushFront(self,key):
        self.insertAfter(self.head,Node(key))
    def pushBack(self,key):
        self.insertBefor(self.head,Node(key))
    def remove(self,x): # 노드 x를 제거
        if(x== self.head or x== None):
            return       
        x.prev.next, x.next.prev = x.next,x.prev
        self.size -=1
    
    def popFront(self): #head 다음에 있는 노드 제거후 그 노드의 데이턱 값을 리턴, 빈 리스트면 none리턴
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        key = self.head.next
        self.remove(self.head.next)
        return key
    
    def popBack(self):#head 이전에 있는 노드의 데이터 값 리턴. 빈 리스트면 None리턴
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        key = self.head.prev
        self.remove(self.head.prev)
        return key


s=DoublyLinkedList()
s.pushFront(7)
s.pushBack(44)
print(s)
s.remove(s.search(44))  # doesnt work
print(s)
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to post the actual code so that people can read it more easily and copy/paste it for testing

Comment: try ```print(self)``` before your ```for x in self``` to see what this loop is actually doing. If you want to access ```Node``` key then need to reference the ```head``` attribute in ```DoublyLinkedList``` while in ```DoublyLinkedList``` scope.

Comment: can copy and paste your code into the input box here and surround whole code with ``` (back ticks under Esc on my keyboard not quotes)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your search code.  What you HAVEN'T shown us is how you create your list.  You don't have any simple "add" functions here, you just have your `splice` function, which requires two existing nodes and a new node.  When you have a list with no nodes, how does that work?

In the following code, I've added "push_back" and "push_front" methods, and if I add 3 items to the list, the search works fine.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key = None):
        self.key = key
        self.prev = self
        self.next = self
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Node({self.key})"
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
        self.size = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        v = self.head.next      
        while v!=self.head :
            yield v
            v = v.next
    def __str__(self):
        return "->".join(str(v) for v in self)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.size
    def push_front(self,key):
        n = Node(key)
        n.prev = self.head
        n.next = self.head.next
        self.head.next.prev = n
        self.head.next = n
        self.size += 1
    def push_back(self,key):
        n = Node(key)
        n.next = self.head
        n.prev = self.head.prev
        self.head.prev.next = n
        self.head.prev = n
        self.size += 1
    def splice(self,a,b,x):  #노드 a부터b까지 떼어내 노드 x뒤에 붙여넣는 연산
        if a== None or b==None or x==None: return
        ap= a.prev
        bn = b.next

        ap.next = bn
        bn.prev = ap

        xn = x.next
        xn.prev = b
        b.next = xn
        a.prev = x
        x.next = a
    def search(self,key):   #key값읖 갖는 노드를 리턴하고 없으면 None을 리턴
        for x in self:
            if x.key == key:
                return x       
        return None

dll = DoublyLinkedList()
dll.push_front(135)
dll.push_front(246)
dll.push_front(357)
print( dll )
print( dll.search(246) )
```

Output:

```
Node(357)->Node(246)->Node(135)
Node(246)
```

Comment: i really appreciate you. thank you i fully apprehend it very well.